# Asp .Net Core 3.0 adding a custom Startup class in tests causes that the Views are not served anymore

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am testing an Asp .Net Core 3.0 MVC application. This a basic sample app create with the command `dotnet new mvc`. In the xunit test project I am testing returning of the view `Index` from the `HomeController`. The test looks like this:

```cs
public class HomeControllerTests
{
    [Fact]
    public async Task ReturnsView()
    {
        const string testProjectDir = "ViewsTestingTests";
        var factory = new TestServerFactory();
        var client = factory.WithWebHostBuilder(builder =>
        {
            builder.UseSolutionRelativeContentRoot(testProjectDir);
            builder.ConfigureTestServices(services =>
            {
                services.AddControllersWithViews()
                    .AddApplicationPart(typeof(Startup).Assembly);
            });
        }).CreateClient();

        var resultIndex = await client.GetAsync("/");
        resultIndex.StatusCode.Should().Be(200);
        var content = await resultIndex.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        content.Should().Contain("Welcome");
    }
}

public class TestServerFactory : WebApplicationFactory<TestStartup>
{
    protected override IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder()
    {
        return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(null)
            .UseStartup<TestStartup>();
    }
}

public class TestStartup : Startup
{
    public TestStartup(IConfiguration configuration) : base(configuration)
    {
    }
}
```

I am using a test startup class because I'll be overriding some methods. When I am using this `TestStartup` class the test doesn't pass. With the following reason:

```
The view 'Index' was not found. The following locations were searched:
/Views/Home/Index.cshtml
/Views/Shared/Index.cshtml
```

But if I use the Startup class from the main project like this:

```cs
public class TestServerFactory : WebApplicationFactory<Startup>
{
    protected override IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder()
    {
        return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(null)
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
    }
}
```

And create Client like this:

```
var client = factory.WithWebHostBuilder(builder =>
            {
                builder.UseSolutionRelativeContentRoot(testProjectDir);
            }).CreateClient();
```

Then the test pass.
Of course I copied the whole Views folder to the test project.

[The solution structure. The Views are in the test project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9rXJU.png)

What is interesting the same test used to work in Asp. Net Core 2.2. Using `builder.UseContentRoot` inside `factory.WithWebHostBuilder` and setting a path to the test project folder doesn't help.
Please help me how to approach this problem.